# How do I sort calculated fields in a report? (MS-Access 2010)

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I've created a report based on this query:

```
SELECT sum(IIF(foo=True, 1, 0)), sum(IIF(bar=True, 1, 0)) from xy;
```

So I get the following result:

```
+---------+---------+----------+
|   Foo   |   Bar   |   ...    |
+---------+---------+----------+
| Value 1 | Value 2 | ...      |
+---------+---------+----------+
```

And then I generate a report from that result:

[image]

My question is; how do I order the values in ascending or descending order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One does not normally "sort" (i.e., change the order of) *fields* in a report. Controls are bound to fields, and controls (usually) have a fixed location in the report layout.

I *think* you want to do something more like this instead:

Create a query that puts the sums into rows instead of columns...

```
SELECT "foo" AS Item, SUM(IIf(foo = True, 1, 0)) AS Total FROM xy
UNION ALL
SELECT "bar" AS Item, SUM(IIf(bar = True, 1, 0)) AS Total FROM xy
```

...and then use the resulting *rows*...

```
Item  Total
----  -----
foo      12
bar       8
```

...in a report. You can sort the rows in the usual way, i.e., via the "Group and Sort" button on the "Design" tab.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm a little rusty on sql. I'm aware of unions but I've never needed to apply them. I'll let you know how it goes.